# When I run iphone app on simulator, screen is white

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I don't know what is wrong with the app it was working fine until I tried to change stuff with the textlabel to textview then it crashed. So I tried changing it back to when it worked and it still crashes. Any ideas?

```
 #import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController

@synthesize labelsText;


-(void)setup {
    titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title 1",@"Title 2",@"Title 3",@"Title 4", nil];
}



-(IBAction) nextclicked:(id)sender{
    titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iology is the scientific study of life. Bam",@"This works? Wow",@"Still Works.",@"garret is the coolest awesome person awesome wowowowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", nil];
        if (step<titles.count-1) {
        step++;
    }
    else
    {
        step= 0;
    }
    labelsText.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    }  



-(IBAction) prevClicked:(id)sender{
    titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Biology is the scientific study of life. Bam",@"This works? Wow",@"Still Works.",@"garret is the coolest awesome person awesome wowowowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", nil];
    if (step>0) {
        step--;
    }
    else
    {
        step =titles.count-1;
    }
    labelsText.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    }  



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
        self.labelsText=nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [labelsText release];
}

@end
```

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {
        UILabel *labelsText;
    UIButton *btn;
    int step;
    NSArray *titles;
                }
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *labelsText;
 -(IBAction) nextclicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) prevClicked:(id)sender;



    @end
```

Comment: You have to link the UILabel outlet in the Storyboard.

Comment: @Jacob What is the crash that you're getting?

Comment: Generally, take a minute to learn about 'snapshot in Xcode or GIT.  That way, when you make a large change that goes bad you will be able to unwind back to a known, working state.

Comment: you resolved your problem?

Comment: I haven't resolved it just yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this:

In your example it should be the **labelstext** and the button too.

[image]

Comment: Ok so what should I change in code, I did what you did in the picture. I'm still having problems.